# Policy for Cloudformation stack creation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm putting together a role/policy for running cloudformation/sam to limit access as much as I can. Is there a general set of policy actions that should be used to run create-stack?

This is for a codebuild which I'm using to create infrastructure using a cloudformation template during runtime of my application.

At the moment I've got a policy which allows full access, because it needs to create the infrastructure within the stack.

But there are only a subset of actions which cloudformation can actually perform and it doesn't need full access. For example, CF can't put items into a dynamodb table.

So this led me to think that maybe there's a basic role/policy that is limited to only the actions which cloudformation is able to perform.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the question? Are you creating a system role to assign to a specific stack? Are you creating a policy that is assigned to a user and you want to limit their access? And in case of the second option, are the users manually executing these cfn stacks?

Comment: thanks @stijndepestel .  The user role I'm creating is actually for a codebuild which I'm using to create infrastructure using a cloudformation template during runtime of my application.   At the moment I've just given it full access, because it needs to create the infrastructure within the stack.  But I'm just thinking that there's only a subset of actions which cloudformation can actually perform.  For example, you can't put items into a dynamodb table.  So this led me to think that maybe there's a basic role/policy that is limited to only the actions which cloudformation is able to perform.

Comment: Can you update the question itself please, so it is clear for future visitors what exactly you were asking?

Answer (score 0):

If you're having to assign a role to a service (such as CodePipeline or CodeBuild) to deploy a stack, you do not only need to assign the necessary CloudFormation permissions (such as `cloudformation:CreateStack` or `cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet`) but also permissions necessary for the deployment of the CloudFormation stack itself.

When you are deploying a stack manually, CloudFormation will use your user permissions to verify access to the services you are deploying/updating. When you're initiating the action from another AWS service, the same thing happens, but with the services from the service role. (Unless you are specifically assigning a role to the CloudFormation stack, [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-servicerole.html)).

Keep in mind if you're constructing such a role, that CloudFormation might need more permissions than you think, such as extra read permissions, permissions to add tags to resources, permissions to delete and/or update those resources when you're deleting/updating the resources etc.